# Java: Making an outline of multiple shapes

Tags: java, graphics, shapes, outline

Say I drew two circles 30 pixels radius and 20 pixels apart. You'd get a cross-over of lines. How can I prevent this crossover?

I've tried looking at various graphics filtering but I haven't found anything suitable.

(This question is not limited to 2 circles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.awt.geom.Area` class to do the operations. It has
add(), intersect(), subtract() methods.

Create one Area (sum of both ovals) and subtract another Area (intersection of both ovals).

---

Working code:

```
int x = 200; int y = 200;
Ellipse2D.Double first = new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,75,75);
Ellipse2D.Double second = new Ellipse2D.Double(x+25,y,75,75);
Area circles = new Area(first);
circles.add(new Area(second));

graphics2D.draw(circles);
```

[image: Two Circles]

Comment: and how would I then draw this new Area?

Comment: It's Shape so use public void draw(Shape s) method of Graphics2D passing the result area.

Comment: Ahh yes of course, shape drawing is Graphics2D. Hmm, it doesn't seem to be working. It's still drawing both circles as they would be drawn separately. Let me check with this in the question.

Comment: Fixed, subtracting the intersection isn't required for the outline I'm after. However, I will bear in mind what it does for future uses.